# Multiple data from js into div

Tags: javascript

The problem is really simple.

Working example for single variable, that leads to display variable first in div "named" container:

```
let first = 5;
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = first; 

<div id="container"></div>
```

But i'd like to do it for multiple signs/variables in such way:

```
let first = 5; 
let second = 10; 
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = first "+" second; 

<div id="container"></div>
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Push all your variables to an array and use the join method with "+" as the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `join` for the task like:

```
["1","2","3"].join("+")
```

From your example:

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = [first,second].join("+");
```

Something like this will be support for all browsers

Answer (score 3):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) :

```js
let first = 5; 
let second = 10; 
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = `${first} + ${second}`;
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your inputs into array

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// append by joining array
document.getElementById('container').innderHTML = arr.join('+');
```